# missing ASP.NET Configuration. from website menu

Tags: asp.net

i try to make this tutorial:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx#Configuring Membership

but the first step is in the Configuring Membership to click ASP.NET Configuration on the website menu. But my VS2015 do not have this menu. Why?

Thanks,
P.

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial is more or less obsolete for VS2015/VS2017. There is a major difference between VS2015 and VS2010. Try tutorials on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/ instead. (I assume that is what you are trying to archive.)

- vahvero